# Issues with displaying unordered list in Next.js version 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

i am working with nextjs 13 and i am printing unordered list in next js which is not working

```
<div className="w-7/12">
                        <div className="tracking-wide">
                            <p className='text-3xl mb-6 font-bold'>Why Choose Android?</p>
                            <p className='pt-2 pb-6'>
                                In an all-iOS world, there are multiple reasons why you should go Android with your app development
                            </p>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Item 1</li>
                                <li>Item 2</li>
                                <li>Item 3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

above is my section which contain unordered list
[image]

i want to get proper unordered list list like in html list

Comment: Share your css too..

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: The same problem exists in Next js 14.
If you look at .next/static/css/app/layout.css you will find the reason for this.
Inside this file they do a reset of ul element giving it a list-style of none.

Comment: Any update on this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using tailwindcss, try this code:

```
<ul className={"list-disc list-inside"}>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```